# Checking for text input in <input type="text"> with jQuery, why doesn't this code work?

Tags: jquery, input, focus, blur

So on my website I want login fields to work where if I click on the username field, the placeholder "username" disappears and I can then type in a username. If I don't type anything in and click away I want the place holder to re appear. The problem that I had was that even if I typed in a username and clicked away the placeholder would still come back in place and replace the username typed in. So here was the code I put in to fix that.

```
$('#user').focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
    $(this).css("color","black");
    }).blur(function(){
        var x = parseInt($(this).val(),10);
        if(x==0){
            $(this).val('Username');
        }
        else{
            $(this).val('youmessedup') /* I put this here just to see 
    if it was the conditional that wasn't working, which it was */;
        }
        $(this).css("color","grey");
});
```

Here is my html code

```
<form>
    <br />
    <input id ="user" type=text value="Username">
</form>
```

I would be posting for the password input also but it would be exactly the same thing just with ID of #pass.

I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.
What I'm thinking is that val is a completely different data type that I think it is? I understand that .val() will grab the value of what is inside the text area. Is that right? If I am in the wrong someone please correct me.

Comment: why not using `placeholder` feature of html5? or if you want it to work on older browser, you can try using a jquery [plugin](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think andri's comment is the best solution, but let me explain why your code does not work.

The problem comes from this line:

```
var x = parseInt($(this).val(),10);
```

You are using `parseInt` on a string which can contain any characters. If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), you will see that

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN.

So the typed username always convert to `NaN`, which is not equal to 0. Hence your `x==0` always fails.

You want to change this line to:

```
var x = $(this).val().length;
```

This way you test the length of the typed username.

Now the problem would be that if the user clicks again on the field, it will erase what is inside, even if he typed his own username. You can prevent this problem by testing if the value is something else than 'Username':

```
if ($(this).val() == 'Username') {
    $(this).val('');
}
```

Your code will then be:

```
$('#user').focus(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'Username') {
        $(this).val('');
    }
    $(this).css("color","black");
}).blur(function(){
    var x = $(this).val().length;
    if(x==0){
        $(this).val('Username');
    }
    $(this).css("color","grey");
});
```

I wrote a small jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dwntZ/). Hope it helps :)